# Only replicate DDL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication

I wonder if there is any easy way to keep the scheme consistent in two different MySQL clusters. Apart from classic replication, I would like to have a special "replication" which would reproduce all DDL queries (CREATE, ALTER, DROP, ...) on another cluster (namely the master of that cluster).

I don't need the actual data to be replicated.

Has anyone ever done or tried anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter replication in MySQL based upon the database in which a query was executed. That doesn't prevent you making changes in other databases, however! So you can do;

```
USE ddl_repl_db;

ALTER TABLE other_db.foo ADD COLUMN <etc>
```

This relies on you configuring your servers correctly. I haven't set up MySQL replication for a while, but IIRC you can both filter what you send out from the master for replication and what you accept on the slave.

Comment: Wow! That's an interesting approach! Very hacky though. I wait a but hoping someone has something what's more straightforward and if none comes, I accept this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Old but still high in search.
So, on you DDL replica set all tables engine to [BLACKHOLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html)